# iOS: Fabric causing crash on ad-hoc distribution, validateFABKitConformance exception immediately after opening

Tags: ios, crashlytics, ad-hoc-distribution, twitter-fabric

The app works fine when run from XCode and only the ad-hoc dist crashes. There doesn't seem to be anyway to to debug this issue since it doesn't present locally.

```
Incident Identifier: 9C35632A-360A-410E-A752-C9BA34CA997A
CrashReporter Key:   d3968346e579b09218f41593d7591290ebd7c231
Hardware Model:      iPod7,1
Process:             myApp [243]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FD154011-4A81-4C50-9F8C-E84404FAE72E/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          com.stuff.myApp
Version:             0.5934.1629 (0.5934.1629)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Date/Time:           2016-03-31 19:30:52.843 -0400
Launch Time:         2016-03-31 19:30:52.191 -0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1844e82d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1959340e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1844e8218 +[NSException raise:format:] + 128
3   myApp                          0x1000fc2dc +[Fabric validateFABKitConformance:] + 512
4   myApp                          0x1000fbda0 __15+[Fabric with:]_block_invoke + 168
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fb1954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fb282c dispatch_once_f + 96
7   myApp                          0x1000fbcf4 +[Fabric with:] + 180
8   myApp                          0x100047774 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:38)
```